# Bluetooth 5 | LE Coded Phy

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

As you know, bluetooth 5 is introduced and its coverage increases up to 200 meter with the help of the LE Coded Phy.
The difference between LE Coded Phy and standart LE Phy is that how many symbols you spend to code one data bit.
According to the Bluetooth specification, there are two type to encode the data which are 2 and 8 coding.

Here is the point that confuses my mind,

The LE Coded Phy property seems like a software trick to me because, there is no difference between sending data and sending coded data. 
Instead of buying Bluetooth chip that supports Bluetooth 5 , can i use Bluetooth chips that support Bluetooth 4.2 to use LE Coded Phy. 
Is it possible, if yes how can i do? if no what the physical layer changes on Bluetooth 5 ?

Thanks for your attention
Have a nice day

Comment: My suspicion is that while *technically* software could deal with it, in practice it probably has to take place much faster than software could handle, hence the need for hardware.  That's just a guess, though.

Answer (score 0):

As much as i learnt, the Coded LE Phy is not a software trick. There exist a specific hardware to detect this kind of Bluetooth message. Because of that, it is not possible to use Bluetooth chips that provides Bluetooth 4.2 specification for sending Coded LE messages.